# Change font-display - when I don't control @font-face stylesheet

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm using the Monotype Fonts subscription. Unfortunately in the Monotype stylesheet `font-display` is set to `swap` which results in Flash of Unstyled Text. How can I have `font-display` set to `block` to get FOIT Flash of Invisible Text? Monotype don't provide a way to control this. Is there a way I can override it in my CSS or HTML? I've tried adding `font-display: block` to the element in my stylesheet, but in the browser dev tools it shows as an error 'unknown property name'.

The link to the Monotype (font) stylesheet is the `<head>`

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.fonts.net">
<link href="https://cdn.fonts.net/kit/xxxxx.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In the browser web dev tools I can see the Monotype sheet:

```
/* @import must be at top of file, otherwise CSS will not work */
@import url("https://cdn.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=xxxxx");
@font-face {
    font-family: "BentonSansProRegular";
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('BentonSansPro/BentonSansProRegular_normal_normal.woff2') format('woff2'), url('BentonSansPro/BentonSansProRegular_normal_normal.woff') format('woff');
}
```

UPDATE

I've tried cloning the Monotype stylesheet, changing the `font-display` to `block` and adding the stylesheet to my server. But the font isn't displaying. The fall-back font is being used. Here's my code:

Head

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.fonts.net">
<link href="https://www.xyz.co.uk/assets/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Stylesheet

```
/* @import must be at top of file, otherwise CSS will not work */
@import url("https://cdn.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=xxxxx");
@font-face {
    font-family: "BentonSansProRegular";
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-display: block;
    src: url('https://cdn.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=xxxxx/BentonSansPro/BentonSansProRegular_normal_normal.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://cdn.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=xxxxx/BentonSansPro/BentonSansProRegular_normal_normal.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: You could define your own font with the same source, or am I missing something?

Comment: The font stylesheet is generated by Monotype. It's a paid for font subscription service. I have no control over the content of the Monotype stylesheet. And I can't seem to over ride the font-display either

Comment: Yea but you can therefore use custom CSS. So don't override it, just clone it and change the `font-display` and `font-family` but keep everything other the same.

Comment: Okay... and change the link to the stylesheet from https://cdn.fonts.net/kit/xxxxx.css to my own server? Where my cloned stylesheet will have font-display:block (the font-family is staying the same). I'll try it...

Comment: That's not worked. I'm guessing the stylesheet and fonts need to be kept together on the Monotype servers?

Comment: Could you share the code that you used?

Comment: There doesn't seem a way to share this with you privately? So I've put the code in my opening post and removed my Monotype "Kit" ID. Thanks

Comment: It should work, but with your added content it is impossible to reproduce it. I added an answer with a font from google-fonts as example. Maybe this helps.

Comment: You're using the dynamic query as a path which doesn't work. Try  `src: url('https://cdn.fonts.net/kit/--API-Key--webFonts/MonardaRegular/normal_normal.woff2') format('woff2');` as a URL structure

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define the font-face yourself, based on the source you have. I demonstrate this for the Google-Fonts font "Roboto":

Normally you would include the following line in the `<head>`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then you could use `font-family: "Roboto"` on any element. To change the `@font-face` declaration just copy the stylesheet that you linked in your head and remove the `<link …>`-element. Now link the copied stylesheet and change it to your liking. For example take the original declaration for `latin`:

```
/* original: latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOiCnqEu92Fr1Mu51QrEzAdLw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

You could change it to:

```
/* customized: latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOiCnqEu92Fr1Mu51QrEzAdLw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Obviously you need to change every occurence of the declared "Roboto"-font-face.

Comment: Hey thanks. It's not quite as easy as with Google Fonts. Because the stylesheet is now on my server and not Monotypes I've updated the source url of the font, to try and link to the font. See my post. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes the stylesheet should be on your server. Only the `url` in the `src` attribute should be on a remote server. Like I said its difficult to debug this. Did you check if the font gets loaded (via the network inspector in the browser developer tools)? Is your CSS-rule that applies the font to a element correct? You could also check the font tab in the developer tools to see if your "new" font is there.

Comment: In dev tool I can see that it is looking for the Benton font on my server. I'll update the src url to point towards the Monotype server...

Comment: So on the cloned stylesheet I've changed the src to url(    src: url('https://cdn.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=xxxxx/BentonSansPro/BentonSansProCondensedBold_normal_condensed_subset1.woff2') format('woff2'); but now the browser isn't even trying to find the font